# Getting type error in python when using for loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, isbn, check-digit

I'm sure this will be a very basic question for you, but I'm making a ISBN check digit calculator for my computing class. My current code is this:

```
isbn = []
results = []

print("Please input your ISBN 1 number at a time")

def isbn_input():
    isbn.append(int(input("ISBN character 1: ")))
    isbn.append(int(input("ISBN character 2: ")))
    isbn.append(int(input("ISBN character 3: ")))
    isbn.append(int(input("ISBN character 4: ")))
    isbn.append(int(input("ISBN character 5: ")))
    isbn.append(int(input("ISBN character 6: ")))
    isbn.append(int(input("ISBN character 7: ")))
    isbn.append(int(input("ISBN character 8: ")))
    isbn.append(int(input("ISBN character 9: ")))
    isbn.append(int(input("ISBN character 10: ")))

isbn_input()

results.append(isbn[0] * 11)
results.append(isbn[1] * 10)
results.append(isbn[2] * 9)
results.append(isbn[3] * 8)
results.append(isbn[4] * 7)
results.append(isbn[5] * 6)
results.append(isbn[6] * 5)
results.append(isbn[7] * 4)
results.append(isbn[8] * 3)
results.append(isbn[9] * 2)

results = sum(results)
results = results % 11
results = 11 - results
print("Your ISBN is'",
      isbn[0],isbn[1],isbn[2],isbn[3],
      isbn[4],isbn[5],isbn[6],isbn[7],
      isbn[8],isbn[9],results,"'")
```

I know this is an insanely inefficient way of doing it, and you're probably crying even looking at it.

The first thing I did to try making it more efficient is by using a for loop. So, I changed:

```
def isbn_input():
    isbn.append(int(input("ISBN character 1: ")))
    isbn.append(int(input("ISBN character 2: ")))
    isbn.append(int(input("ISBN character 3: ")))
    isbn.append(int(input("ISBN character 4: ")))
    isbn.append(int(input("ISBN character 5: ")))
    isbn.append(int(input("ISBN character 6: ")))
    isbn.append(int(input("ISBN character 7: ")))
    isbn.append(int(input("ISBN character 8: ")))
    isbn.append(int(input("ISBN character 9: ")))
    isbn.append(int(input("ISBN character 10: ")))
```

to a for list, but I haven't figured out how to do this yet. This is the bit I need help on (Also, I know the function is pointless. Our teacher demanded we have one in, but if anyone can find a better way of doing it then that would be amazing too)

Thanks a lot for the help. Again, if you spot anything which could be made better, then please do. (Also, this is python 3.)

Comment: Where's the type error? Show us the code that generated the error, and show the full traceback of said error.

Comment: @mhlester: Here: `isbn[0] * 11`. Call `int(isbn[0])`.

Comment: @SzieberthAdam He is already converting the input to int before adding to the isbn list

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To simplify the input:

```
isbn = [int(input("ISBN character {0}: ".format(i))) 
        for i in range(1, 11)] # or 'format(i+1)' and 'range(10)'
```

This uses a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) to simultaneously loop and built the list of integers.

Alternatively, take the whole input at once and convert it into individual integers:

```
isbn = list(map(int, input("Enter ISBN: ")))
```

Here [`map`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map) applies `int()` to convert each of the characters in the `input` string in turn.

Comment: Those are pretty advanced concepts... you should add some explaination of how list comprehensions and `map` are doing.

Comment: Thanks a lot, the comments bit was especially helpful, so thanks for putting in the extra time for helping with that! Works great now.

Answer (score 1):

A simple `for` loop for input would be

```
for i in range(1, 11):
    isbn.append(int(input("ISBN character " + str(i) + ":")))
```

To read everything at once, you could do

```
isbninput = input("ISBN: ")

if len(isbninput) != 10:
    raise Exception("wrong number of digits")

for digit in isbninput:
   isbn.append(int(digit))
```

Python, being awesome, has more compact ways to write those simple loops. See jonrsharpe's answer for those. If you're still a beginner and don't fully understands how those more complex syntactic constructs work, you should do two things:

- Prefer the code that you could write, and read, in your sleep, and the code that you find more aesthetic
- Learn how to use them. They're awesome.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. While I've used the other answer, I'll definitely have a read of it and learn what you suggested.